# Setting Column Headers When Adding Columns To a Table Via Macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm working on this macro that automatically adds columns to a table based on other columns in the table.  So here's the functionality:

I have a number of columns in this table headed "CY 2010" - "CY 2020".  These years will inevitably change.  I then want to add a column to the table for each "CY" column.  Furthermore, I'd like the headers of these columns to match the year, but say "Content Volume YEAR"

currently, I have the following code that adds columns appropriately:

```
Sub AddContentValueColumns()
'
' AddContentValueColumn Macro
' Adds yearly vehicle content value columns to Propulsion data table.
'

'
    last = [A1].Value               ' cell contains number of "CY" columns in sheet

'   Debug.Print (last)

    For Count = 1 To last
        Dim oSh As Worksheet
        Set oSh = ActiveSheet
        oSh.ListObjects("PropTable").ListColumns.Add
    Next Count

End Sub
```

This works to add the columns, but it currently just adds the columns to the end of the table labeled as "CY 2021", etc.

So how do I modify that code above to name the columns?

Thanks.

-Sean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how to change the column name:

```
last = [A1].Value               ' cell contains number of "CY" columns in sheet
For Count = 1 To last
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Set oSh = ActiveSheet
    Dim oLc As ListColumn
    Set oLc = oSh.ListObjects("PropTable").ListColumns.Add
    oLc.Name = "COLUMN NAME" & last
Next Count
```

Comment: +1, I never realized ListColumns had names! This will simplify some code.